# How to find which tab a particular Chrome process refers to

Tags: windows, google-chrome, task-manager

I often have 6 or 7 separate Chrome windows open, often with 5-10 tabs in each.  When I look at Windows Task Manager, I see each chrome.exe process, with some using a large amount of memory.  How can I find which particular tab the process refers to?  I want to know which one uses the most memory and close that tab instead of having to close every Chrome window.  Is there any way to get this information?  This is on Windows Vista, but it is the same on other versions of Windows as well.

Comment: (6 or 7) * (5 to 10) = (30 to 70) Why in Torvalds' name do you have so many tabs open at one time?!?

Comment: _only_ 6 or 7 with _only_ 5-10 tabs? Ha ha.  This is perfectly normal for creative people doing research juggling many projects who get interrupted to deal with other things.  Puddingfox is obviously just a beginner :P

Comment: @jamesbtate I literally have about 50 to 300 tabs open at any given time.... LOL

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> to bring up the Chrome 
Task Manager under Windows, or select it from the Window menu under MacOS. It will tell you how much memory and CPU each tab uses, and its process id if you enable the process id column. You can also switch to a tab by double-clicking it, or kill its renderer process.

If there's still a sneaky process that isn't showing in Chrome's Task Manager, you can launch Chrome with the command line switch `--task-manager-show-extra-renderers` (from the Command Prompt or a shortcut under Windows, or from the Terminal or an Applescript under MacOS), but my current experience (2019-07-13) suggests that this *may* cause Chrome to sometimes crash, at least under MacOS.

Comment: Awesome.  Just what I was looking for.  Thanks.

Comment: The double-click bit is really useful for subframes, which are more difficult to identify than normal tabs

Answer (score 29):

Use the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>Esc</kbd> shortcut key to bring up the Task Manager,

or go to 
the wrench icon and go to `Tools -> Task Manager`.

You'll be able to see the CPU usage of every tab and plugin as well as memory usage.

[image: Chrome Task Manager]

Comment: The TM came up for me with the "Page" column as wide as the window. Had to stretch the window to see the good stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Open the chrome task manager and right click one of the headers (task, memory footprint, etc.). From the list that appears, choose CPU Time.

Now open windows task manager and make sure CPU time is also one of the headers by clicking view -> select columns -> CPU Time -> OK. Now sort by CPU time in both task managers.

Chrome task manager will show you what the tab is, then match the CPU time to the process in windows task manager to close exactly what you want from the windows task manager (if closing it from the chrome task manager is not sufficient for you).

I found that when closing a process from the chrome task manager, it does not always close from windows task manager, so I prefer to use windows. Hope this helps you too.

Answer (score -2):

Chrome should have a separate process for each tab. Find the Chrome process that is using up the most CPU porwer (using task manager) and kill it.

Comment: There is usually a master process, and that one often takes up the most CPU. If you kill that process, you risk killing the entire browser. Better to just use the built-in task manager, which shows stats for each tab.

Comment: And, in addition to what `nhinkle` said:  Chrome _does not_ necessarily have a separate process per tab.  That's just one of the options.  There are others, and you've no idea how the questioner has xyr Chrome configured in this regard, since xe hasn't provided that information.

Comment: So when I looked at the Task Manager, there was just a single Shockwave Flash process that was taking up the whole CPU, but I can't tell through which tab it is running.

Comment: What part of **Chrome does not necessarily have a separate process per tab.** is so unclear to you that you persist in looking for a single tab to be associated with this process?  End the process and you'll discover, from an unslaught of little sad pictures, the harsh truth that your Shockwave Flash process is doing _all_ of the Flash plug-in work for _every tab_ that has Flash on it.