# How do I determine which Chrome tab is using all my CPU?

Tags: google-chrome, flash, tabs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find which tab a particular Chrome process refers to](https://superuser.com/questions/133845/how-to-find-which-tab-a-particular-chrome-process-refers-to)

I have many Chrome tabs open and I do not want to close them yet.  However, one of them is killing my CPU via Shockwave flash.  Is there any way to tell which tab is the culprit?