# In MacOS Chrome, if "Browser" process (according to Chrome Task Manager) is using 90% CPU, what URL or extension is the culprit?

Tags: macos, google-chrome

Sometimes when I open a new webpage in Chrome, my Mac (Big Sur 11.2.1) will suddenly start maxing out one CPU. But sometimes even after I close the tab (and for good measure, other recently-opened tabs too), the CPU stays pegged at 100% for at least a minute or two. This happened today and I opened Chrome's Task Manager and it said that the "Browser" process was using ~90%, with one of the renderer processes using ~20%.  None of the other Chrome processes were >10% CPU. It persisted for at least a minute before I got impatient and quit Chrome, after which the problem finally went away. When I re-open the same tabs, the problem doesn't recur. It's intermittent and seemingly random.

When this happens again, how should I diagnose which page or extension is problematic?  Related questions:

- What runs in the "Browser" process as opposed to the various tab and extension processes?
- Is there any way to tell which URL or extension is chewing up cycles inside that "Browser" process?
- If a page is running poorly-behaved JavaScript, will closing the tab kill the script?  If not, does it eventually get killed after the tab is closed?  If yes, what's the timeout?
- Is it possible for CPU to be be consumed by tabs that I've closed? If yes, in what circumstances could this happen?

Note: this is *not* a dupe of [How to find which tab a particular Chrome process refers to](https://superuser.com/questions/133845/how-to-find-which-tab-a-particular-chrome-process-refers-to). That question is about basic tab resource troubleshooting. This question is about what to do when basic troubleshooting with Chrome Task Manager isn't helpful.