# Is it possible to retrieve the PID number of a specific chromium tab?

Tags: linux, chromium, pid

I'm trying to introduce a solution to [a problem](https://github.com/rfjakob/earlyoom/issues/280) and in order to achieve that, I need to get the PID number of the Chromium process that displays a specific webpage (ie. `http://localhost:4025`).

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

In chrome, you can open the Chome task manager using shift-escape. This task manager will tell you all processes created by extensions and all tabs, and lists their process id.

Comment: If this works for Chromium, then this post becomes [duplicate](https://superuser.com/questions/133845/how-to-find-which-tab-a-particular-chrome-process-refers-to).

Comment: @harrymc yes, I suppose this is a duplicate. Couldn't find it that quickly. But yes, this task manager feature is part of every chrome based browser. Not sure this is the answer OP is looking for now that I reread his question. He may want a commandline thingy

Comment: We need to find that pid outside of Chromium, ie. from command line. We can't kill a specific chrome process with an external application without interaction otherwise.

Comment: Chromium does not expose this information to my knowledge. You can find out the PID's, but not which PID is linked to what tab.